# как прочитать все страницы WORD

Tags: ms-word

подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести все страницы ворд. у меня файл из трех страниц, код, который написан, выводит только первую станицу

file = docx.Document('13356_1_289.docx')
all_paras = file.paragraphs
len(all_paras)
for para in all_paras:
print(para.text)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.